# Twitter Bootstrap - Styling does not display on mobile browsers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

My website is located at http://www.elgami.com/

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap for my styling. Everything works fine on desktop, but my styling does not display on mobile browsers, except for when I hard-code it in, of course. What could be going wrong?

My header is displayed below:

My css files are located in the folder "css" in my public_html root directory.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hypercycle™ - Personalize Your World.</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/blog.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,800,900">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,200,400,600">

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='typicons.font-master/src/font/typicons.min.css' />

</head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
```

from line 32 of your blog.css. It is telling the browser to only style it when the site is larger than 1200px.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the @media tag entirely really messed with the layout (but that's probably an issue that is peculiar to my website), so I did the following:

```
@media (min-width: 0px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
```